# HP Pavilion Notebook overheating on Windows 10

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, temperature

My HP Pavilion 17-e026sg notebook has been having troubles maintaining the right temperature ever since I bought it. It was shipped without an OS and I first installed Windows 8 where it only overheated when I played games (which was worse enough though). Now for Windows 10, I am having issues with an overheating CPU already right after installing Windows:

[image: CPU temperature information from HWiNFO; idle temperature]

At first, I thought it was the GPU which overheated (since that was what my BIOS told me), however I found out that this doesn't seem to be the issue:

[image: GPU temp information fron HWiNFO; idle temp]

Please also note the number of GPU memory errors which is huge. Reading a bit on the internet showed me that this may come due to a previous overheating of the GPU.

When I use elementaryOS (Ubuntu 18.04) on this machine, I'm not getting any problems with temperature, I can even play games without having the notebook overheating, so it seems to be an operating system problem.

Can I maybe solve this problem through changing the core voltage and if so, how can I change this? the BIOS doesn't really give me any chance to do so:

[image: BIOS screen]

What I already tried:

- updated BIOS
- cleaned the fan
- tried another OS

Comment: If you're fine on ubuntu and are having problems on windows, there's nothing to do inside BIOS to help. Temperatures higher than 100° are unlikely to be caused by Windows10 only ... are you sure it's not malware?

Comment: Probably the heatsink assembly needs new thermal paste. It is unlikely related to Windows 10 itself, but as mentioned by hextech malware can use the CPU and GPU and cause an overloaded and overheated system. If it has been overheating in the past then it will only get worse as fans wear out and thermal compounds dry out. Youay need to dismantle the laptop to replace thermal compounds and clean out or replace fans.

Comment: "Can I maybe solve this problem through changing the core voltage".. you won't find options like this on most laptops.. and CERTAINLY not HP.  ***If you find no other solution***.. try a "laptop cooler".  Not a great solution.. but better than overheating.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. @hextech I'm quite sure about that since I didn't only format the hard drives multiple times, I even changed them and reinstalled Windows several times until I tried Ubuntu which finally didn't drain that much power.
Mokubai that's probably the only way, I hope I can find spare parts for that laptop.
SeñorCMasMas I tried a laptop cooler, it works _quite_ well but not as for my wishes.

Comment: Are you sure you're using your dedicated GPU on windows? Do you have the right drivers? Edit: The CPU is also quote old, disabling stuff like transparency effect on windows should have a big effect on its own - consider optimising your windows (but those temperatures aren't normal ... you might need to do what mokubai mentioned)

Comment: @hextech no, I'm not sure about this and I always have the latest drivers setup for the GPU. however I really don't think that this setup would be overwhelmed by transparency effects of W10. I will try with a new cooler and new thermal paste for now.

Comment: I think I meant saying "could", not "should" have a big effect. But using dedicated GPU for display instead of using your CPU would also free some processsing power up and could help with getting the temperatures down.
You can check which GPU is used when opening Task Manager and seeing which GPU is showing any load.